# How can I import model from another app in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization, custom-authentication

I have my custom user model

now I want to use it in another app to register a person

In my signup/forms.py I'm trying to do this

signup/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from customauth.models import MyUser

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'phone', 'type': 'tel', 'class': 'form-control'}), label='')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}), label='')
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Name'}), label='')
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), label='')

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('mobile', 'email', 'username', 'password')
```

second line doesn't work. I can't import this model
I tried to do this with project name before app name
but.. then I have an **importError with no module named "projectname.appname"**

signup/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import UserForm

# def signup(request):
#     return render(request, 'signup/signup.html')


def signup(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, auto_id=False)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'signup/signup.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered},
        context
    )
```

customauth/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, mobile, email, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            mobile=mobile,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, mobile, email, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            mobile=mobile,
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

customauth/admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'username')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'username', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('username',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'landing',
    'django_summernote',
    'backend',
    'customauth',
    'signin',
    'signup',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.MyUser'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_project',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'www',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}


def uploaded_filepath(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return os.path.join('django-summernote', today, filename)

SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # Using SummernoteWidget - iframe mode
    'iframe': True,  # or set False to use SummernoteInplaceWidget - no iframe mode

    # Using Summernote Air-mode
    'airMode': False,

    # Use native HTML tags (`<b>`, `<i>`, ...) instead of style attributes
    # (Firefox, Chrome only)
    'styleWithTags': False,

    # Set text direction : 'left to right' is default.
    'direction': 'ltr',

    # Change editor size
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '480',

    'attachment_upload_to': uploaded_filepath,
    # Use proper language setting automatically (default)
    'lang': None,

    # Or, set editor language/locale forcely
    'lang': 'ko-KR',

}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "common-static/"),)

STATIC_URL = '/common-static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

Comment: Have you added your app to the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Comment: Of course I added both @Panda

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you provide a stacktrace and your settings?

Comment: Have you create `__init__.py` files on every app directory?